# action passed down from connect decorator is initially undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have the following smart component and I am specifying the `initialUpload` function is a required func:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import UploadForm from '../../components/UploadForm/UploadForm';
import HeaderSelection from '../../components/HeaderSelection/HeaderSelection';
import { initialUpload } from '../../redux/modules/Upload';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

console.log(typeof initialUpload); //function

@connect((state) => {
  return {
    file: state.getIn(['upload', 'file'])
  };
}, {
  initialUpload
})
export default class Home extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialUpload: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UploadForm handleFilesChange={this.props.initialUpload}/>
        <HeaderSelection/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I get the error message:

> warning.js:36Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `initialUpload` is
>   marked as required in `Connect(Home)`, but its value is `undefined`.

The function is wrapped in dispatch and passed down the component hierarchy fine so I am confused as to what is going on.

Comment: Which component is calling Home?

Answer (score 2):

@connect is assigning the `static propTypes` to the resulting rapping component and not to `Home` itself, which is rather a weird behaviour! I think it is caused by ES7 transformation, this behaviour was not present in previous versions

A work around is to define the propTypes on the wrappedComponent outside class definition:

```
@connect(...)  
export default Home extends Component{  
    render() {  
        // ....  
    }  
}  

Home.WrappedComponent.propTypes = {  
    initialUpload: PropTypes.func.isRequired  
}
```

another option would be not to use the decorator & use connect directly